# How To Select Random Object From NSArray With Strings Using arc4random

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, arc4random

As the title says... I need to select a random object from the array (moodArray) and i think it would be easier using arc4random. If you need anymore information just let me know... 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

```
id randomObject = [moodArray objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform([moodArray count])];
```

Comment: I tried this and i get the 'unused variable' warning. How do i use the variable or is this all it needs to work?

Comment: Oh for goodness sake! You get that warning when you declare a variable and then don't do anything with it. If you extract and object from your array into a variable called randomObject, you then need to **USE** that variable somewhere. If you're not using it, don't bother creating it. It just wastes CPU time and battery life.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString *myString = [moodArray objectAtIndex:arc4random()%[moodArray count]];
```